# Force using an Alsa driver

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, intel

I have an HP Spectre x360 13t and I'm unable to play audio out of the speakers. I know that our friends over at Archlinux was able to get this working. The difference seems to be that Archlinux loaded a different driver by default. Here is their output of 'pactl list cards':

```
Card #0
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 6
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "sof-hda-dsp"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HP-HPSpectrex360Convertible14t_ea000--87F7"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a0c8"
        device.product.name = "Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Profiles:
        HiFi: Play HiFi quality Music (sinks: 4, sources: 2, priority: 8000, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: HiFi
    Ports:
        [Out] HDMI3: HDMI3 Output (type: HDMI, priority: 700, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Part of profile(s): HiFi
        [Out] HDMI2: HDMI2 Output (type: HDMI, priority: 600, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Part of profile(s): HiFi
        [Out] HDMI1: HDMI1 Output (type: HDMI, priority: 500, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Part of profile(s): HiFi
        [Out] Speaker: Speaker (type: Speaker, priority: 100, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Part of profile(s): HiFi
        [Out] Headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 200, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Part of profile(s): HiFi
        [In] Mic2: Headphones Stereo Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 200, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Part of profile(s): HiFi
        [In] Mic1: Digital Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 100, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Part of profile(s): HiFi
```

and here us Ubuntu's (21.10, kernel 5.15):

```
Card #0
        Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw
        Driver: module-alsa-card.c
        Owner Module: 22
        Properties:
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "sof-soundwire"
                alsa.long_card_name = "Intel Soundwire SOF"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_sof_sdw"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3-platform-sof_sdw"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof_sdw/sound/card0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                device.product.id = "a0c8"
                device.product.name = "Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller"
                device.string = "0"
                device.description = "Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        Profiles:
                output:stereo-fallback: Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 37868, available: yes)
                off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
        Active Profile: output:stereo-fallback
        Ports:
                analog-output-speaker: Speakers (type: Speaker, priority: 10000, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
                        Properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
                        Part of profile(s): output:stereo-fallback
                analog-output-headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
                        Properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
                        Part of profile(s): output:stereo-fallback
```

Note that Archlinux loads 'snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp' while Ubuntu loads 'snd_soc_sof_sdw'.

So my question is: How do I force the loading of the one that Archlinux does? I know there are mechanisms to put 'blacklists' and 'option .. index=-2' in my alsa-base.con but doing this to the snd_soc_sof_sdw does not seem to do anything. I have a feeling there's something basic I'm missing.

Thanks

Comment: what is the status of `systemctl --user status pulseaudio` ?

Comment: [broken up into two messages to avoid limit]:

% systemctl --user status pulseaudio

● pulseaudio.service - Sound Service

     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-11-12 12:29:07 PST; 1 day 1h ago

Comment: TriggeredBy: ● pulseaudio.socket
   Main PID: 1932 (pulseaudio)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18683)
     Memory: 5.5M
        CPU: 2.815s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pulseaudio.service
             └─1932 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal

Nov 12 12:29:06 mies systemd[1923]: Starting Sound Service...
Nov 12 12:29:07 mies systemd[1923]: Started Sound Service.

Comment: JoKeR: I'd be interested to know what this tells us.

Comment: Please add complete output to your question so it can be clearly readable, also add output for `pacmd list-sinks | awk '/index/ || /name:/ || /alsa.card_name/ || /device.description/'`